# Monaca: Where is the jquery after I install it in monaca with onsenui

Tags: jquery, monaca, onsen-ui2

In Monaca, I installed JQuery using File | Manage JS/CSS components...
Added the JQuery (Monaca version) 2.03
Pressed save, and don't see the JQuery file(s) in my project.

Where are they?

Comment: I hope this saves somebody the hours I spent getting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it: You have to click the settings thingy in the project, and above the "show hidden files" there is a REFRESH button that you have to hit.

The `JQuery-Monaca` folder is under components, but you have to explicitly use the `src="www/components/monaca-jquery/jquery.js"` and that script has to come first, before the `loader.js` (which uses  only `src="componenets/loader.js"` without the `www/`.

I don't know why this is so.

Comment: And see the company's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to use `src="www/components/monaca-jquery/jquery.js"` this. All you need is `<script src="components/loader.js"></script>`.

As you may notice, in the `<head>` tag in `index.html` file, there is the following line by default:

```
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
```

This line is required by Monaca in order to include any JavaScript library that you add via `JS/CSS Components` page (`Config --> JS/CSS Components`). For example, in your case, you add `jQuery (Monaca Version)`. The jQuery library is included to your project via `<script src="components/loader.js"></script>`.

All added JS libraries are under `www/components/` folder. In this case, you are right; the newly added library is not showing under the folder unless `Refresh` manually. We are fixing this issue now as well. Thanks for your report. :)

We hope this clarifies how the JS libraries are added and called in Monaca project.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it clarifies this.